# if só executa else

Tags: php, mysql, if, include

Olá pessoal tenho essa função `if`ela recolhe uma variável vindo de login.php e faz uma verificação pra escolher entre dois menus. Só que não importa o resultado dentro da variável `$permt` ele sempre escolhe else. Alguém pode me apontar meu erro cometido.

```
<?php
include"in/login.php";

$hi=$svc['nome']."";
$permt=$svc['nivel']."";

?>

<?php   
if($permt==1) {

    require_once"in/menu.html";
    echo "$permt";  
}
else{
     require_once"in/menu2.html";
     echo "$permt";
    }
?>
```

Para complementar esse é o conteúdo de login.php

```
<?php
include "conecta.inc";


$log= mysqli_query($conn,"select nome,nivel from usuarios where login='$doc' ");
$svc=mysqli_fetch_array($log);
if($cont){
    header("Location: ../home.php"); exit;
    }
```

Comment: faz um echo após recebimento de dado na variável $permt para ver o que está sendo recebido.

Comment: ja fiz amigo recebo o valor 1 esperado

Comment: Não tem como sabermos, o problema está em outro lugar: http://ideone.com/dvrb5W

Comment: curiosamente se eu remover um sinal de '=' ele passa a mostrar a primeira opção, mas trava nela também.

Comment: tente utilizar apóstrofo ou aspas exe: ($permt=='1') ou ($permt=="1") se funcionar é devido o tipo de informação recebida ser string e não inteiro.

Comment: Tem certeza que o seu `if` não está usando **===**? `if($permt===1)` essa condição joga para o `else`, mas o que tem no seu código não apresenta erro.

Comment: fiz os teste sugeridos pelo Wilson mesmo problema persiste, unica coisa diferente é que adicionei echo dentro de `if` e `else` e so ocorre perfeitamente em if.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talvez seja porque está comparando uma string com um inteiro, só para garantir, converte para inteiro antes de comparar e faz uma comparação de valor e tipo '===' (três sinais de igual).

Também  alterei `$permt=$svc['nivel']."";`  para `$permt=$svc['nivel'];`

```
$permt=intval($permt,10);
var_dump($permt); // para debugar se continuar dando erro.
if($permt===1) {
    echo 'op 1';
}else{
    echo 'op 2';
}
```

Código completo:

```
<?php
include"in/login.php";
$hi=$svc['nome']."";
$permt=$svc['nivel'];
$permt=intval($permt,10); // poderia converter na linha anterior...
if($permt===1) {
    require_once"in/menu.html";
    echo "$permt";  
}else{
     require_once"in/menu2.html";
     echo "$permt";
}
```

Lembrando que a saída do `echo` é diferente do `var_dump`... Qual a saida de `var_dump($svc['nivel']);` ?

Espero ter ajudado e desejo boa sorte em seu projeto!

Comment: com essas alterações todos os `echo` tem o valor de 0 induzindo naturalmente ao `else`

Comment: Qual a saida de var_dump($svc['nivel']); ?

Comment: 1 fiz um echo antes de tudo e realmente esta correta.

Comment: a saída do echo é diferente do var_dump... faz um teste com var_dump pode ser?

Comment: Feito amigo ele me deu valor NULL suspeito que você achou o possivel erro.

Comment: Caso tenha lhe ajudado a resolver o problema fico feliz se escolher a minha pergunta ou dar +1.

Comment: Ajudou sim agora sei que estou tendo um problema no arquivo base que coleta a informação.